# How to compare all entries in columns of 2 csv files (csv1 and csv2) in python/pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, file-io

I have 2 CSV files:

CSV1:

```
"Hypervisor","IP","ABCD","Operating System","Domain","Memory","No. CPU","Availability (%)","Last Collection Time","lol"
"lglac125.lss.com","10.247.52.125","VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599031E9"
"lglac126.lss.com","10.247.52.126","VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9"
"lglac127.lss.com","10.247.52.127","VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","0.0","1.558599031E9"
"lglac128.lss.com","10.247.52.128","VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9"
"lglac129.lss.com","10.247.52.129","VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9"
```

CSV2:

```
"Hypervisor","IP","Arrays","Operating System","Domain","Memory","No. CPU","Availability (%)","Last Collection Time","DummyColumn"
"lglac125.lss.com","10.247.52.125",,"VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599031E9","A"
"lglac126.lss.com","10.247.52.126",,"VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9","B"
"lglac127.lss.com","10.247.52.127",,"VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","0.0","1.558599031E9","C"
"lglac128.lss.com","10.247.52.128",,"VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9","D"
"lglac129.lss.com","10.247.52.129",,"VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9","E"
"DummyRow","10.247.52.129",,"VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047","lss.com","524278.03125","4.0","100.0","1.558599931E9","F"
```

I am trying to compare all the entries of each column (if available in csv2), with corresponding rows. If there is any entry missing or changed, i need to raise a flag. **There could be possibility of add or removal of any column in both the files.** So i need to first check if the column x is there in csv2 and then match the entry for the same column from csv1.

I've been struggling with this for three days now and couldn't come to a solution. I highly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and `indicator=True` and [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) out the `both`:

```
matching_cols=df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).tolist() #find matching columns to merge
df1.merge(df2,on=matching_cols,how='outer',indicator=True).query("_merge!='both'")
```

This will show you the uncommon data between the dataframes

---

```
             Hypervisor             IP                 Operating System  \
0  lglac125.lss.emc.com  10.247.52.125  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047   
5  lglac125.lss.emc.com                 VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047   
6              DummyRow  10.247.52.129  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047   

        Domain        Memory  No. CPU  Availability (%)  Last Collection Time  \
0  lss.emc.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558599e+09   
5  lss.emc.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558599e+09   
6  lss.emc.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09   

   Arrays DummyColumn      _merge  
0     NaN         NaN   left_only  
5     NaN           A  right_only  
6     NaN           F  right_only
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

Assume csv1, csv2 imported to pandas as `df1`, `df2`. Find matching columns using `intersection` on columns and sort it. Passing it to `df1` and `df2`. Finally, `eq` on this sub-set of matching columns of `df1` and `df2`

```
matched_list = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).sort_values()
df1_mask = df1[matched_list].eq(df2[matched_list])

Out[853]:
   Availability (%)  Domain  Hypervisor     IP  Last Collection Time  Memory  \
0              True    True        True  False                  True    True
1              True    True        True   True                  True    True
2              True    True        True   True                  True    True
3              True    True        True   True                  True    True
4              True    True        True   True                  True    True
5             False   False       False  False                 False   False

   No. CPU  Operating System
0     True              True
1     True              True
2     True              True
3     True              True
4     True              True
5    False             False
```

**Note**: *I change `df1.loc[0, 'IP']` to `10.247.52.124` to show `False` in one value of row 0 of `df1` for demonstration*

From this `df1_mask`, you may plug it to `df1` to check for `NaN`. Any `NaN` is either original value `NaN` or it is changed between `df1` and `df2`

```
df1[df1_mask]

Out[854]:
         Hypervisor             IP                 Operating System   Domain  \
0  lglac125.lss.com            NaN  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047  lss.com
1  lglac126.lss.com  10.247.52.126  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047  lss.com
2  lglac127.lss.com  10.247.52.127  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047  lss.com
3  lglac128.lss.com  10.247.52.128  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047  lss.com
4  lglac129.lss.com  10.247.52.129  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047  lss.com

         Memory  No. CPU  Availability (%)  Last Collection Time  lol
0  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558599e+09  NaN
1  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09  NaN
2  524278.03125      4.0               0.0          1.558599e+09  NaN
3  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09  NaN
4  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09  NaN
```

**Note**: your `df1` has column `lol` but no value, so it is originally `NaN`

---

Or You can check on `df2`

```
df2[df1_mask]

Out[855]:
         Hypervisor             IP  Arrays                 Operating System  \
0  lglac125.lss.com            NaN     NaN  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047
1  lglac126.lss.com  10.247.52.126     NaN  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047
2  lglac127.lss.com  10.247.52.127     NaN  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047
3  lglac128.lss.com  10.247.52.128     NaN  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047
4  lglac129.lss.com  10.247.52.129     NaN  VMware ESXi 5.5.0 build-9919047
5               NaN            NaN     NaN                              NaN

    Domain        Memory  No. CPU  Availability (%)  Last Collection Time  \
0  lss.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558599e+09
1  lss.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09
2  lss.com  524278.03125      4.0               0.0          1.558599e+09
3  lss.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09
4  lss.com  524278.03125      4.0             100.0          1.558600e+09
5      NaN           NaN      NaN               NaN                   NaN

  DummyColumn
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andy.This helps. I need one more clarification.. Is there a way i can print /identify only those rows and columns which are been modified. Or for which df1_mask shows False ?

Comment: @GauravPhagre: just do `df1[~df1_mask.all(1)]` . It will show only rows having any `False`